# render a razor partial only if it has not already been rendered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have an MVC app that exposes dynamically generated "pages" (the data comes from a db). One page can contain 1 or more "content(s)" and some "content(s)" might require the user to be logged in. (A content can be a form for instance and 1 page could contain several forms).

When a "content" requires to be logged in, a "LoginBox" that is a simple partial linking to the login page is displayed

The question is:
How to handle the situation where I have multiple contents on a single page if I only want to have 1 loginBox per page.

In other words how to "merge" multiple partials or how to render a partial if and only if it has not already been rendered ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Instead of check and show the login on each included content do it on the page which includes those contents.

Comment: Ok, so on the page that includes those contents, if I understand well, I could do \@ViewBag.hasLoginBox = true when the LoginBox is rendered for the first time and render a partial only if \@ViewBag.hasLoginBox != null & != false